# Ember.js external json for Store

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a json file that lives on the on the server that is hosting my Ember.js app. I want to use that json as the "store" for the app (it will only be for reading). I'm not sure the best way to do this. Do I need to use a RESTAdapter to hit the file, or somehow use it as an external FixtureAdapter, or is there some other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is it possible to send the file when the page is loaded, or does it have to be fetched afterwards?

Comment: I suppose it could be fetched at any time. I just have a URL to it, and need to be able to read it.

Comment: For read-only content like this, you could just do `$.getJSON` in your route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the fixture adapter as described [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-fixture-adapter/). If the file is static, you can just add it to your page as a script tag and be done with it. If the file changes per user, you'll probably have to write some server-side logic to generate it. If that's the case, I would append it to your HTML file as a self executing function or something. Either way, if your data isn't changing, the FixtureAdapter is your best bet. You don't want to have to mess with the RESTAdapter or trying to write your own.