# Asynchronously update EmberJS Fixture Adapter

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a table of links that I'm trying to pull from an external JSON file. Some simple HTML and Handlebars:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Links</th></tr>
  </thead>
  {{#each model}}
  <tr><td>
    <a target="_blank" {{bindAttr href="url"}}>{{title}}</a>
  </td></tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

And from my app.js, I'm trying to load the JSON asynchronously into my Fixture Adapter:

```
var externalLinksJSON = [{
    id: 0
}];

$.getJSON('externalLinks.json', function(data) {
    externalLinksJSON = data;
})
.fail(function() { console.error("There was an error loading externalLinks.json"); });

App.ExternalLink.FIXTURES = externalLinksJSON;
```

Debugging the JavaScript shows that the `externalLinksJSON` variable is getting updated successfully, but EmberJS isn't updating the HTML with the newly fetch JSON. I'm trying to avoid blocking the browser with synchronous calls. Is there a way in EmberJS to bind the Fixtures so that it updates when the values change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was under the impression the Fixtures adapter was for static testing data defined in the client's javascript, so my concern is whether it is designed to update after the app js has loaded.. Have you tried putting the Fixture data clientside to see whether that is the problem?

From the [Ember site](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/using-fixutres/):

> Fixtures are a way to put sample data into an application before
>   connecting the application to long-term persistence.

Perhaps try using the REST adapter of Ember Data, or dealing with API calls by [without Ember Data](http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was trying to use Fixtures because of the answer to me [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778364/ember-js-external-json-for-store) since I'm not actually hitting a REST API, just a static file. Edit: I'll take a look at the "without Ember Data" option, though.

Comment: That answer suggests adding it as a file with a script tag, again being accessible on load for the Fixture adapter instead of being added via AJAX after load. Some test JSON anywhere in your app will let you see whether that's the problem or whether it lies elsewhere.